# Cannot log in via SSH after uploading SSH key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I just uploaded an SSH key to my server and now I can't login anymore...
SSH is running on port 3333.

puTTy: `pageant failed to answer challenge`

Terminal give me this when trying: `ssh -vvv "user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 3333"`

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 3333 [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 3333 port 22: Connection refused
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys).

How can I login again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the quotes off.  You should run

```
ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 3333
```

The quotes were needed for `ssh-copy-id` because `ssh-copy-id` is just a script that itself calls ssh with the parameters you gave it (where it becomes `user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 3333` without quotes), but when running ssh directly, you don't need the quotes.

Comment: You're right. But the message after `ssh-copy-id` says something different: `Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 3333'"`  That's not correct.

Comment: Then you should file that as a bug against whoever manages your ssh package.